# Porque as dependências do meu projeto não são detectadas no setup do projeto (Windows Forms)?

Tags: c#, winforms, instalador, dependências, setup

Estou tentando gerar um Setup de uma aplicação Windows Forms usando a extensão "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects". Porém quando eu tento atualizar as dependências do Setup não aparece nenhuma, mesmo meu projeto tendo dependências.

```
<PackageReference Include="ESC-POS-USB-NET" Version="1.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="QRCoder" Version="1.4.3" />
<PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="110.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Stub.System.Data.SQLite.Core.NetStandard" Version="1.0.117" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Text.Encoding.CodePages" Version="6.0.0" />
```

Segui algumas posts de blogs e em todos as dependências apareciam mesmo sem ter que atualizar a pasta de dependências.

Não acontece nenhum erro de build e tudo aparenta estar normal mas quando eu tento instalar o aplicativo usando o wizard ele instala uma Dll invés do executável do meu programa.

Comment: Se a sua aplicação for .net core, essas dependencias nao irao aparecer mesmo. voce teria que nos mostrar o processo que voce fez

Comment: o que voce adicionou na pasta da aplicação?